# How to display an array in one line in nodejs CMD

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, excel

the task is to display the items of the array in the console in one line, so that I can copy and paste it later in excel.

the problem is how the console display's the data, when the items of the array is greater than 4 it automatically displays the data in column manner, I want it to stay in row manner so that when I copy and paste it to excel it will go to the correct row and column.

Any Idea's how do I approach this? I attached a snapshot of the console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try like this using `JSON.stringify(array)`, See my demo on `CMD`

[image]

It'll print your array inside a single quote on a single line as far it can show it. So, now you cab copy and paste it to excel and it will go to the correct row and column.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is `process.stdout.write(param.toString())` where param is your array.

```
var c = ['rose', 'power', 'daisy', 'katie', 'melina'];
process.stdout.write(c.toString());
```

The output would be

```
rose,power,daisy,katie,melinatrue
```

Ignore the true in the end and you would be good. Hope it would help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON#stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on the array:

```js
var arr = [{"id":1,"name":"foo"},{"id":2,"name":"bar"},{"id":1,"name":"foo"}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

In Chrome another option is to use `copy`:

1. console.log(arr) // not stringified.
2. Right click the array in the console, and select "store as global variable"
3. Write copy(temp1) // or whatever other name chrome assigned
4. Paste wherever you want